# How to add a class on classpath in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have the following project structure in Intellij:

[image]

I am actually working with a `maven` project and all I wanna do is just run the project. Unfortunatelly I dont understand why but when I run the class called `GenerateGraph` it shows me the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class graph.GenerateGraph
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: graph.GenerateGraph
```

I dont understand why this happens- it is the first time I encounter something like that. When I go on `project structure` I see the following:

[image]

**Run configuration:**
[image]

seems like it doesnt even see that the graph package has a class inside. Could someone maybe help me understand what has happened? Is it because I renamed the package after importing the project? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Your project structure looks correct; the UI shows only directories, not individual files. Please attach a screenshot of your run configuration.

Comment: Try mvn clean install in the command line.

Comment: @DanielJacob mvn clean install shows the same error

Comment: @yole I added it

Answer (score 2):

Your project is not setup correctly.

You have `reverseGraph` marked as the sources root. In this case, `src` is the source folder.

The typical Maven project structure is `src/main/java` for non-test source files and `src/test/java` for tests.

What I'd recommend is modifying your folder structure:

1. Remove `reverseGraph`
2. Move `src` to the root of the project.
3. Add a `src/main/java` folder, and move your `graph` folder into that.
4. Reimport the Maven project in IntelliJ, and it should automatically flag the `java` folder in `src/main` as the sources root.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the dependencies are not correctly set up - because you do not have this project opened as Maven project in IDE. Please import this project as Maven project, see steps from [Open an existing Maven project﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) IntelliJ IDEA documentation section.